# preg_match next line issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If i have the following Text

```
#Welcome to the world of Hello World Again
#Hello World Again
Hello World Again

#Other Stuff
Other
```

Im using this command

```
preg_replace('/[^#|^ ]Hello.*/m', 'Hello Again', $content);
```

My output keeps giving me

```
#Welcome to the world of Hello World Again
#Hello World AgainHello Again

#Other Stuff
Other
```

What i want is

```
#Welcome to the world of Hello World Again
#Hello World Again
Hello Again

#Other Stuff
Other
```

Any ideas why that is, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the line start and end matchers `^` and `$`, respectively:

```
preg_replace('/^Hello.*$/m', 'Hello World Again', $content);
```

Comment: @Angel.King.47, You don't have to ignore the `#`. The `^` anchors the expression to the left side of the string. It means that it will only match lines that start with "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the newline. Try this:

```
preg_replace('/([^#|^ ])Hello.*/m', '\1Hello World Again', $content);
```

It includes everything matched by `[^#|^ ]` in the replacement string.

Alternatively, include a line break in your replacement string:

```
preg_replace('/[^#|^ ]Hello.*/m', PHP_EOL . 'Hello Again', $content);
```

You can also simplify your regular expression:

```
`/^[# ]Hello.*$/'
```

Comment: can i not get regex to ignore the end and start line and replace only the inside characters